# circleci config.yml: 'Invalid template path ./.circleci/file.s/backend.yml'

Tags: cloud, devops, cicd

I have written this code in the job command named Infrastructure Deployment.

```
  deploy-infrastructure:
docker:
  - image: amazon/aws-cli
steps:
  # Checkout code from git
  - run:
      name: Ensure back-end infrastructure exists
      command: |
          yum -y install gzip tar 
          aws cloudformation deploy \
            --template-file .circleci/files/backend.yml \
            --stack-name "updapeople-backend-${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID:0:7}" \
            --parameter-overrides ID="${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID:0:7}"
```

but every single time it gave me the same error I am pretty sure the name is totally correct.this path is actually on github and I am trying to build a full automated Pipline for CI/CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an actual `checkout` step (https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference#checkout) before that "Ensure back-end infrastructure exists" step:

```
deploy-infrastructure:
  docker:
    - image: amazon/aws-cli
  steps:
    # Checkout code from git
    - checkout
    - run:
        name: Ensure back-end infrastructure exists
        command: |
            yum -y install gzip tar 
            aws cloudformation deploy \
              --template-file .circleci/files/backend.yml \
              --stack-name "updapeople-backend-${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID:0:7}" \
              --parameter-overrides ID="${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID:0:7}"
```